# Updating sql databe values

Tags: sql, sql-server

In table `Requisitions` i have tow columns `RequisitionID` and `Code`.

I need to update Code value based on RequisitionID value in this format.

RN-000`RequisitionID`/2017 so output will be RN-0001/2017 for example if `RequisitionID` =1

i have tried the below query but it didn't work.

```
update [dbo].[Requisitions] set [Code]='RN-000 "'RequisitionID'"/2017'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modification in your query:

```
update [dbo].[Requisitions] set [Code]='RN-000'+RequisitionID+'/2017'
```

if above didn't work, use:

```
update [dbo].[Requisitions] set [Code]='RN-000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,RequisitionID)+'/2017'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to us a `+` to `CONCATENATE` them together. You will also have to cast `2017` to a `VARCHAR` so that the `+` operator isn't interpreted as addition, rather concatenation.

```
declare @table table (RequisitionID int, Code varchar(64))
insert into @table values
(1,'RN-000')

update @table
Set Code= Code + cast(RequisitionID as varchar(1)) + '/2017'
Where RequisitionID = 1

select * from @table


+---------------+--------------+
| RequisitionID |     Code     |
+---------------+--------------+
|             1 | RN-0001/2017 |
+---------------+--------------+
```